# How to insert a white gap between specific columns in a plot of corrplot?

Tags: r, plot, heatmap, r-corrplot

I want to add a white gap as a separator between specific columns in the correlation heatmap generated by `corrplot` in R.

Code:

```
library(corrplot)
M = cor(mtcars)
corrplot(M, method = 'number')
```

1. `corrplot`

[image: Image1]

2. I want a white gap between the second and third columns as shown below.

[image: Image2]

Is there any way to do this in R?

Answer (score 0):

We could do it this way: Just enter a column with zeros:

```
library(corrplot) 
M <- cor(mtcars) 
M <- cbind(M[, 1:2], rep(0, nrow(M)), M[, 3:ncol(M)])

corrplot(M, method = 'number')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Tarjae, Thanks a lot for your answer, but I don't want a blank column, there are still the grids inside, I want a gap, like gap_col in pheatmap. Are there other solutions for this?

Comment: Ok. this was my first intuition. I will try and change if I find an alternative.